# Удаление всех элементов из Layout

Tags: android, activity, android-layout

Каким образом можно удалить все `View`-элементы на layout'е, которые были добавлены из кода (не имеют `id`), без перезагрузки `Activity`?

Подойдут любые варианты. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Для удаления всех `View` из виджета-контейнера (такие, как любой `Layout`) в классе `ViewGroup`, от которого наследуются все виджеты-контейнеры есть метод [`removeAllViews()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()):

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
// или если контейнер на разметке
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

...
layout.removeAllViews(); // удалить все View из LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен метод `ViewGroup#removeAllViews()` - он как раз и удалит все дочерние вьюхи у той, на которой этот метод будет вызван

Comment: А это метод какого класса?

Comment: @Ker_Jen это метод не View, а ViewGroup (любого layout)

Comment: @pavlofff Я так понимаю, что это не статический метод и придется создавать экземпляр класса ViewGroup. Но ведь имплементируется метод onLayout. Как без него?

Comment: Попробуйте описать свою проблему подробнее, отредактировав вопрос. Нужно создать экземпляр, естественно. Я не понимаю, какая проблема связана с onLayout()

Comment: @pavlofff ViewGroup ведь абстрактный, там есть метод onLayout имплементирующийся. Что он делает, и зачем он нужен, просто код методами, которые не используются, не хочется забивать.

Comment: @pavlofff Ох, сглупил. Я понял зачем он нужен.

Comment: @Ker_Jen вам нужно создать не абстрактный экземпляр `ViewGroup`, а вызвать этот метод для того layout, в котором надо удалить все вложенные в него `View`